# TortoiseHg - How to create feature branch starting at an earlier rev

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I worked for three weeks on the default branch, committing frequently.  I would now like to update to a point 3 weeks ago and push/pull etc with default as if those 3 weeks never existed.  Ideally, I could say "Mercurial, please treat all work over the past 3 weeks as a new feature branch" so I can continue working on default until I fix what needs to be fixed.  Then I can return to my feature branch.

I know I should have just started a feature branch 3 weeks ago, but we all mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

As long has you've haven't pushed to a public repo you can:

1. update to the point 3 weeks ago
2. create the named branch
3. rebase 'ahead commits' on default to the named branch.
4. You may want to the change the 'Phase' of the named branch to secret so you don't push it accidentally.

If you haven't used Rebase before you will have to enable the extension in File -> Settings -> Extensions.

Otherwise if you have pushed then:

1. update to the point 3 weeks ago.
2. Just commit changes (create two heads on default)
3. When you've done, before pushing merge one default head onto the other default branch.

Comment: No, I need to push only new changes and leave those 3 weeks OUT for now.  I can merge it all later, but I need to push between then and now, essentially pretending those 3 weeks never happened.  And yes, I pushed those 3 weeks multiple times.

Comment: If you've public repo allows, you could create a new default head with push -f then you could just do that. Then when you've done just merge the heads.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend cloning to a new, local repository from the revision 3 weeks ago. Work on this new repository and then, when ready, push back to parent (the local one).

I like working with clones rather than branches since it allows me to have a simpler view of the statuses. In my case, have an eclipse work space for each repository that I can switch between.

This might not be exactly what you asked for, but it's a valid solution to your need.

I hope this helps.